# Can't match "go-http-bot" for HTTP_USER_AGENT in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, bots

I want to force bots out of certain designated areas, and they don't necessarily listen to `robots.txt`

I feel like this may be a simple regex thing that I'm not getting.

This works:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|spider|crawl|archiver|seeker|slurp|facebook|twitter) [NC]`

But this does not work to kick out `Go-http-client`:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|spider|crawl|archiver|seeker|slurp|facebook|twitter|go\-http\-client) [NC]`

Comment: What if you remove `[NC]` and prepend `(?i)` to regex?

Comment: Turns out I forgot to adjust another rule in the .htaccess file.  The regex is correct as is.